# RTL8101E not working [ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have some problem with my lap top TOSHIBA SATELLITE L50-B-1EF.
I bought this laptop without any OS and installed Ububntu 14.04 in UEFI mode with secure boot.
Neither wired connection nor wi-fi are not working... 
I tried to install driver from official Realtek website - r8101-1.026.00, but it cann't be istalled... 
**Error:**

```
abraham@nihgt-flyer:~/r8101-1.026.00$ sudo make
[sudo] password for abraham: 
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
  CLEAN   /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/Module.symvers
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101_n.o
  CC [M]  /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/rtl_eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/rtltool.o
  LD [M]  /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
  INSTALL /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.13.0-32-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
abraham@nihgt-flyer:~/r8101-1.026.00$ sudo make install
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
  INSTALL /home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src/r8101.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.13.0-32-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abraham/r8101-1.026.00/src'
abraham@nihgt-flyer:~/r8101-1.026.00$
```

**lspci -nn**

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:54:44:ac:dd:86  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:55560 (55.5 KB)  TX bytes:17581 (17.5 KB)
          Interrupt:105 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:26353 (26.3 KB)  TX bytes:26353 (26.3 KB)
```

I've read many themes, but didnt found the solution for my problem and I really need help.
Thnx!

Comment: I see no error at all in your compile. It appears to have built successfully. What driver is loaded now? lsmod | grep -e r8101 -e 816 Thanks.

Comment: error was after "install":
$abraham@nihgt-flyer:~/r8101-1.026.00$ sudo make install
***Can't read private key; lsmod | grep -e r8101 -e816 - answer: r8101  178563  0; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The message 'can't read private key' is not an error; it is an informational message that doesn't prevent compilation and installation of the driver r8101. In fact, looking at lsmod, the listing of loaded modules, it is active and has created an ethernet interface eth0. It has not yet connected, however.

Please reboot so we have a clean slate and then run:

```
dmesg > r8101.txt
```

Find the file r8101.txt and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

We see nothing remarkable; that is, fixable so far. Would you please also do:

```
nm-tool > r8101v2.txt
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e etwork -e eth0 | tail -n20  >> r8101v2.txt
cat /etc/network/interfaces  >> r8101v2.txt
```

Paste as above and give us the link, please.

I suggest you try:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex half autoneg off
```

Can you now connect? If it works, we'll write to one file and make it persistent.

Let's get your wireless going. According to *dmesg*, it is:

> [14e4:4365] type 00 class 0x028000

Since you still have the install USB or DVD, insert it and drill down to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d > dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. r8101.txt link http://paste.ubuntu.com/9528694/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I did it. Logs link http://paste.ubuntu.com/9529213/
I should to say that I tried to connect tl-wn8200nd wifi adaptor and he was found wifi points. I cann't connect to them because it not my points, I have just cable right now. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea why nm-tool says, "Wired Properties Carrier: off" Is the ethernet plugged in to the router with a known working CAT5 or 6 cable? Are the LEDs lit at both ends?

Comment: I have not idea why nm-tool says "Wired Properties Carrier: off". :(
I have cisco EPC2100R2 modem without led where cable connection. But laptop's led is not lighting when I connect cable.
I think this is cat5 cable.

Comment: No, it not works:( I attached log if you need it  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9530711/

Comment: I don't know what else to do: "<info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 70, deferring action for 4 seconds)" Shall we turn our attention to the wireless? Do you have the install USB or DVD?

Comment: dvd or usb with ubuntu installation image?

Comment: Yes, exactly? If you have it, we can find and install the wireless driver.

Comment: Yes, sure, I have it

Comment: Please see my edit above.